# Error no 14 while installing PostgreSQL using yum

Tags: postgresql, yum, rhel6

I am trying to install PostgreSQL on RHEL 6.3 using yum. I am getting a error while installing postgreSQL using yum.

Command:

> yum install postgresql95-server postgresql95

Error:

> Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, downloadonly, refresh-packagekit,
>   security
>   https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-6Server-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
>   [Errno 14] problem making ssl connection Trying other mirror. Error:
>   Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository:
>   pgdg95. Please verify its path and try again

I have tried using 'yum clean all', but it's the same.

Help me to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following commands to sort this issue:

> yum clean all
>
> yum update

after these two commands use your installation command.

> yum install postgresql95-server postgresql95

This sorted out my problem after several retries.